# OpenERP, Aptana - debugging Python code, breakpoint not working

Tags: python, odoo, aptana

I have created Odoo v8 PyDev project in Aptana. When I run the openerp server from Aptana, and set a breakpoint in my file product_nk.py, the program does not stop at this break point although I navigated to the Odoo web pages where the functionality is linked to the code with breakpoint.

What am I possibly missing in the setup and what I need to do to have the program stop at the set breakpoint in Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could happen if you run your server in "run" mode and not "debug" mode.
If you are in "run" mode the breakpoints would be skipped. 
In Aptana, go to the "run" -> "debug" to run it in debug mode.